# How to override laravel 6 vendor view template files

Tags: templates, laravel-6

I want to override a vendor module view file ( name.blade.php ) in laravel. Is this possible? If so, How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out using below command.

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Using this command, it gives list of available vendor Providers and tag that can be overridden. Attached sample screenshot of the same.

[image]